# Cython with Scikit-build: dynamic module does not define module export function

Tags: python, c++, c, cython

I have been doing some tests with the cython hello world example in [scikit-build-sample-projects](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build-sample-projects/tree/master/projects/hello-cython), and noticed that if I change the name of some files and their corresponding fields in CMakeLists.txt the compilation works with no error but when trying the result, the following errors can come:

For python3:`ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_...`

For python2:`ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (Init_...`

and looking more into the [c++ file](https://github.com/scikit-build/scikit-build-sample-projects/blob/master/projects/hello-cpp/hello/_hello.cxx) I found these parts:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
PyMODINIT____FUNC init_hello(void)
{
  (void) Py_InitModule("_rectangle", hello_methods);
}
#else /* PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 */
static struct PyModuleDef hello_module_def = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "_rectangle",
  "Internal \"_rectangle\" module",
  -1,
  hello_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__rectangle(void)
{
  return PyModule_Create(&hello_module_def);
}
#endif /* PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3 */
```

where if I change the "_hello" parts to the new name I had defined ion the project everything works again.

Now I want to try the [original Cython's rectangle class example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) and am not sure how to make it work because of the above part. It seems to me that I should change the c++ code of rectangle.

Does anyone know how we can reproduce the Cython's rectangle example with scikit build taking into account the above issue?

Comment: normally, the name of the extension  `XXXX` should be the same as in` PyInit_XXXX` and the same as the name of the pyx-file, i.e. `XXXX.pyx`. If you don't follow this rule, you better know what you are doing.

Comment: so at the moment I am giving the same name for them, but in scikit build, it seems to always need the above parts. It's not clear how to reproduce the Rectangle example of Cython.